# How to wrap multiple uneven height .col- siblings in Bootstrap .row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nopcommerce

I have a lot of products and I need maximum 6 products for each line,
so I let for each product `col-lg-2` (6*2 = 12 bootstrap cols) and I think it should break to next line automatically (starts on the left side), isn't it?

but the second line is broken and start from the fourth col instead.
Please, what is the reason for it and how can I fix it?

see the image below maybe it will simulate better than my English.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please add your code to understand your problem.

Comment: product list height problem -  add your code

Comment: You should consider flex box technique

Comment: This happen cuz the uneven height of the boxes. try setting a fixed height for each boxes, say .box{ height: 250px}

Comment: @JinuKurian Thanks, i define height to 288px and it fix the problem.

Comment: @Idoshhh Just see my answer, setting fixed height may cause problems if you are adding more texts inside the box. Go with the javascript method as given in the answer, It will set equal height to all boxes. So alignment issue won't happen.

Comment: Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete

Comment: the reason behind it is that, your content blocks are of not equal height. which is causing `float` elements to behave this way. Using CSS, add `clear:float` to every 7th bootstrap in **LG** view, similarly after every 3rd div, add `clear:float` to 4th div in **SM** view similarly for **XS** after on every 3rd div.

Comment: What do you expect in SMALL & MEDIUM screen? @Idoshhh

Comment: @DeepakYadav `clear:float` is invalid CSS. You'd need `left` or `both` for it to work. Also, on `xs` you need `clear` on each `odd` child, not on each `third`. Details matter. Cheers!

Comment: @Andrei - thanks I got it wrong, yes it is `clear:left`. And for XS devices, you are again correct

Answer (score 2):

Use .clearfix class before ending  row

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
       <div class="clearfix"></div> //use this before end of row
</div>
```

or if possible use not more than 6 container in one row 
Take another row and add next 6 container

Comment: Using `.clearfix` before the end of a row is utterly pointless. Why would you want to do that? And how does it fix the floating problem of `col-`s summing up more than 12 `col`s?

Answer (score 1):

You gotta give fixed `height` for the boxes. Since its height may vary with `text`, alignment issue will occur.

for eg:

```
box{
 height: 300px;
}
```

A common and quick way to solve this problem is use equal-height using JavaScript.

https://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/

```
equalheight = function(container) {

    var currentTallest = 0,
        currentRowStart = 0,
        rowDivs = new Array(),
        $el,
        topPosition = 0;
    $(container).each(function() {

        $el = $(this);
        $($el).height('auto')
        topPostion = $el.position().top;

        if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
            for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
                rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
            }
            rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
            currentRowStart = topPostion;
            currentTallest = $el.height();
            rowDivs.push($el);
        } else {
            rowDivs.push($el);
            currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
        }
        for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
            rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
        }
    });
}
$(window).resize(function() {   //to work in resize
    equalheight('.col-lg-2.col-md-3.col-sm-4.col-xs-6');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
 equalheight('.col-lg-2.col-md-3.col-sm-4.col-xs-6');
});
```

Comment: @Yoshi : I got this from another site which I didn't remember and I'm using this script for years. :) Credits added.

Answer (score 1):

In Twitter Bootstrap (below `4.x`), by default, all classes starting with `col-` (`[class^="col-"]`) have `float: left`. When the `row` is filled, the next item looks for the next available spot to align itself to the left. If the tallest item from the previous row is not the last one in row, it will create a floating point under its immediate successorm just as in your picture. A `1px` difference is enough for this to happen.

Basically, *you want to tell each item that should start a new row to ignore existing floats*. You want to set `clear:left` on ***each element following a***

- multiple of 6 on large screens (for `col-lg-2`),
- multiple of 3 on small and medium screens and (for `col-sm-4`, implying `col-md-4`, since `md` is missing)
- multiple of 2 on `xs` screens (for `col-xs-6`)

effectively telling it to ***start a completely new row***,

Here is the CSS translation of the above:

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row>.col-lg-2:nth-child(6n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1199px) {
  .row>.col-sm-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .row>.col-xs-6:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: left;
  }
}

/* you don't need the line below. it's for StackOverflow snippet only */ 
body {padding: 15px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/214/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/173/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/187/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/185/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/135/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/231/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/191/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/201/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/185/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/154/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/179/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/235/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/185/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/142/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="well">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/280/" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a col-md-12 div after your row class. That worked for me

like

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
------------//Your lg columns go here, please use md instead of lg if not worked
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's what you are proposing. https://jsfiddle.net/ku6067x1/. Why do you think it would work?

Answer (score 0):

this happens because of the different height between the elements, try to use rows to break the lines

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
```